# Run intersects function in PHP?

Tags: intersection, php

I have an old script that used to connect to a postGIS DB and basically perform:

```
$sql="select *
from mobile.regions_ne
where intersects(geom_wgs84,GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT (".$lng." ".$lat." 0)'))";
```

However, since we have moved to ZF2 and no longer connect to any databases (we only parse feeds now), we cannot perform the `intersects` call.

Our application uses Doctrine, and always creates a sqlite DB. The module is run on linux servers for our live web app, as well as on local machines that run Windows with the Node Webkit version of our app.

How can we easily perform the same code in PHP without using postGIS? If it's not possible, then it looks like we'll need to create an intermediary service that we would use on the production server to parse the feed AND connect to a postGIS server, however we want to avoid this if possible.